# Issues making a flyover image popup in a Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I started writing a Greasemonkey script as a start for learning JavaScript. What the script does is simply when you hover your mouse pointer over a thumbnail image, if enlarges that picture to a popup window.

And I'm almost done. But there's a few snags...

1. when the mouseenter event fires, it spawns a popup and it **also** loads that same image in the webpage itself! Thus preventing it from executing the mouseleave part too, I think.
2. How do I set the width and the height of the popup dynamically according to the particular measurements of the loading image?
3. In the '/thumbs/75x60/' part, I want to use the * wildcard to replace '75x60' (as in * x * ) so that any size of thumbnail pic would be affected. How do I do that?

See http://jsfiddle.net/JWcB7/6/

The HTML is like:

```
<div id="profPhotos">
    <a class="profPhotoLink" href="...">
        <img width="95" height="130" src=".../thumbs/163x130/8f/fd/588x800_1319044306_9223981.jpg">
    </a>
    <br>
    <a class="profPhotoLink" href="...">
        <img width="75" height="60" src=".../thumbs/75x60/f0/d9/604x453_1319044306_9254715.jpg">
    </a>
    ... ...
</div>
```

The JS is:

```
$('#profPhotos .profPhotoLink > img').bind
(
    "mouseenter mouseleave", myImageHover
);

function myImageHover (zEvent)
{
    if (zEvent.type == 'mouseenter')
    {
        var imgurl = this.src.toString();
        //need to replace '/thumbs/75x60/' part with '/photos/' to get the full size image
        var bigimg = imgurl.replace("/thumbs/75x60/", "/photos/");  
        window.location.href = bigimg;
        popup = window.open(bigimg,"popwindow","menubar=0,resizable=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,width=600,height=800") //how to set the width and the height dynamically
    }
    else
    {
        popup.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the image to load in the same page as well don't do this! :

```
window.location.href = bigimg;
```

Or did you want the image there somehow as well as the popup?

~~~
As for the wildcard replace, that's easy.  Change:

```
var bigimg = imgurl.replace("/thumbs/75x60/", "/photos/");
```

To:

```
var bigimg = imgurl.replace(/\/thumbs\/[0-9x]+\//i, "/photos/");
```

~~~
Resizing the popup gets tricky Do you really want a ***popup*** on mouseover!!?  Would a flyover larger image do?

I do not recommend using an actual popup (`window.open()`) to show the large images.  Because of security blocking and cross-site restrictions, this can be a right pain.  But it's possible with Greasemonkey.

Instead, I recommend you show the image in a pseudo-popup dialog.  Do this by inserting a `<div>` that's `position: absolute;` and has a high `z-index`.

The `mouseenter` event would then change the `src` of the image inside the div.

Putting it all together, here is a complete Greasemonkey script that generates simple popup images on mouseover:

You can [see the code in action at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/obapaj/2/edit#preview).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    _Popup Image Flyover, Mark I
// @include http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

/*--- Create the div and the image that will be pointed to our large
    pictures.
*/
$("body").append ('<div id="idLargePicturePopupWindow"><img></div>');

/*--- In case the popup covers the current mouse position, it must also
    trigger the hover change.  This avoids certain annoying blinking
    scenarios.
*/
$('#idLargePicturePopupWindow').bind (
    "mouseenter mouseleave",
    {bInPopup: true},
    myImageHover
);

/*--- Activate the mouseover on the desired images on the target page.
*/
$('#profPhotos .profPhotoLink > img').bind (
    "mouseenter mouseleave",
    {bInPopup: false},
    myImageHover
);

function myImageHover (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.type == 'mouseenter') {

        if ( ! zEvent.data.bInPopup) {

            var imgurl = this.src.toString();
            /*--- Need to replace '/thumbs/75x60/' part with '/photos/'
                to get the full size image.
            */
            var bigimg = imgurl.replace(/\/thumbs\/[0-9x]+\//i, "/photos/");

            $("#idLargePicturePopupWindow img").attr ('src', bigimg);
        }

        $("#idLargePicturePopupWindow").show ();
    }
    else {
        $("#idLargePicturePopupWindow").hide ();
    }
}


/*--- Here we add the CSS styles that make this approach work.
*/
GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    #idLargePicturePopupWindow {
        position:               absolute;
        background:             white;
        border:                 3px double blue;
        margin:                 1ex;
        opacity:                1.0;
        z-index:                1222;
        min-height:             100px;
        min-width:              200px;
        padding:                0;
        display:                none;
        top:                    10em;
        left:                   10em;
    }
    #idLargePicturePopupWindow img {
        margin:                 0;
        margin-bottom:          -4px;
        padding:                0;
    }
]]></>).toString () );
```

Comment: #1 is okay now.

and for #2, I tried that one but didn't work out. Let me explain a little more. Since there can be thumbnail images of various sizes (say 65x50, 80x75 etc) I want this script to work no matter whatever those two values are. Right now, it only works for 75x60 since it's hard-coded.

#3, I looked into that too. But that wouldn't work because different images have different values in the URL. I'm not sure what a flyover larger image is but from the sound of it, I think that's exactly what I want! If its not too much of a hassle, I'd like to see the code for both please. :)

Comment: For #2, did you try the replacement code I gave?  That is NOT hard-coded and will work for any thumbnail size.   As for the popup... That gets complicated because of "same origin" security, so it's hard to demo on jsFiddle.  I've got to do my paying job now, but I'll post the code in a few hours.

Comment: oh! I didn't just copy it, I wrote it by looking at your code and I had missed the 'i'. That's why it didn't work. sorry about that. I was refering to _my_ line as hard-coded. My bad. btw can you please explain this part (/\/thumbs\/[0-9x]+\//i) of the replacement code a bit? Sure, take all the time. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Added the code to the answer. For the replacement code explanation, see http://www.regular-expressions.info . Basically, I escaped the slashes and `[0-9x]+` searches for any combination of numbers and/or the letter `x`.

Comment: I made a few changes in the CSS code block to fit the image I had in mind now its working perfectly! I tested on Firefox and I learned that Chrome doesn't support @require, that must be why the script doesn't work in Chrome. Anyway, its all good for a start. Thank you very much again for your help and support through it all. Cheers! :)

Comment: I want to improve the cross-browser compatibility of the script. Some advice? [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624210/greasemonkey-script-in-chrome-not-working)

Comment: Please ask a new question for that.