# Getting jQuery and GM_addStyle to work in a Chrome userscript based off of a working Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, userscripts

I wrote a simple [Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/120111) that enlarges thumbnail pictures in a flyover popup. It uses a lot of jQuery in it. It works just fine on Firefox. But not on Chrome since it doesn't support @require.

I came across this [solution](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/14/using-jquery-with-a-user-script) for this matter. But the script didn't work on Chrome even after I integrated it with the get-around code. I just put all my script code inside the solution code's main function.

Is it wrong?  If anyone can point out where is the problem, and what I can do to get it right, it'll be very much appreciated.

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function main() 
{
  $("body").append ('<div id="idLargePicturePopupWindow"><img></div>');

$('#idLargePicturePopupWindow').bind 
(
    "mouseenter mouseleave",
    {bInPopup: true},
    myImageHover
);

$('#profPhotos .profPhotoLink > img').bind 
(
    "mouseenter mouseleave",
    {bInPopup: false},
    myImageHover
);

function myImageHover (zEvent) 
{
    if (zEvent.type == 'mouseenter') 
    {

        if ( ! zEvent.data.bInPopup) 
        {

            var imgurl = this.src.toString();
            var bigimg = imgurl.replace(/\/thumbs\/[0-9x]+\//i, "/photos/");

            $("#idLargePicturePopupWindow img").attr ('src', bigimg);
        }

        $("#idLargePicturePopupWindow").show();
    }
    else 
    {
        $("#idLargePicturePopupWindow").hide();
    }
}

GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    #idLargePicturePopupWindow 
    {
        position:               absolute;
        background:             white;
        border:                 none;
        margin:                 1ex;
        opacity:                1.0;
        z-index:                1222;
        min-height:             100px;
        min-width:              200px;
        padding:                0;
        display:                none;
        top:                    2em;
        left:                   50em;
    }
    #idLargePicturePopupWindow img 
    {
        margin:                 0;
        margin-bottom:          -4px;
        padding:                0;
    }
]]></>).toString () );
}

addJQuery(main);
```

Comment: The `<><![CDATA[ ...` construct won't work in Chrome.  Also that jQuery injection is not the best.  I'll post a more detailed answer in a few hours if somebody doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: I kinda guessed it too. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main problems and 1 *possible* problem:

1) Do not wrap `GM_addStyle()` inside the `main()` function.  `GM_addStyle()` only works in script scope, it will not work injected to the target page (which is what that `main()` and `addJQuery()` business does).

2) The current code uses [E4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML) to make a multiline string to send to `GM_addStyle()`, but Chrome doesn't support E4X.

Alas, [the multiline string hack that Chrome does support (for now)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5571069/331508) does not work in Firefox.

That means it's slightly harder to code realistic styles with `GM_addStyle()` if you wish to support both browsers.  Use the multiline escape character (`\`) like so:

```
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    #idLargePicturePopupWindow  {               \
        position:               absolute;       \
        background:             white;          \
        border:                 none;           \
        margin:                 1ex;            \
        opacity:                1.0;            \
        z-index:                1222;           \
        min-height:             100px;          \
        min-width:              200px;          \
        padding:                0;              \
        display:                none;           \
        top:                    2em;            \
        left:                   50em;           \
    }                                           \
    #idLargePicturePopupWindow img  {           \
        margin:                 0;              \
        margin-bottom:          -4px;           \
        padding:                0;              \
    }                                           \
" );
```

¿3?) That particular version of `addJQuery()` may not always work (race condition).  Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: It works fine on Chrome now. Not on Firefox though. But its okay. I just made 2 versions. Thank you very much. Merry X'mas and Happy New Year!

Comment: btw if this injection method is not best practice, is there a better way to integrate third-party JS libraries to userscripts?? or shall I ask a separate question for this so it might be helpful for others too?

Comment: Happy holidays!  If the changes were properly made, then the script should work on both FF and Chrome without needed 2 versions.  As for the library load, I prefer to check that the library variable is defined inside a timer.  Sometimes a library will not be ready until shortly after the `<script>`'s load event has fired.  (Although I don't think that is the case for jQuery.)

Comment: I'll check again then. By the way, I'm not quite clear about using timer in JavaScript. Can you please give or direct me to a good example? Thank you.

Comment: In response to problem 1: given that one makes use of jQuery by injecting the user script in the page, how _can_ one call GM_* functions from inside the callback function? Or if that's just not possible, how can one make use of both jQuery _and_ GM_* functions in a user script in Chrome?

Comment: @JelleFresen, You don't have to use jQuery by injecting the user script.  That's just a convenient hack in most cases.  If you want to use GM_ functions from *inside* jQuery driven code, than you cannot inject the jQuery.  Open a new question for more information on that.  Note that this question and answer already show the use of both jQuery and GM_functions -- just not sharing scope.